# Using Guava Collections2 transform method to work as Apache CollectionUtil.forAllDo

Tags: java, apache-commons, guava

I've read some post comparing Guava and Apache Commons, and most of the posters prefer using Guava.

I also prefer using Guava, though I frequently find myself the need to combine Guava and Apache Commons abilities.

For example, I want to perform an operation on all elements of a collection.
The only way I can do it using Guava is by calling the `transform` method.
But it uses `Function` which gets a value and returns another one, while I don't need to return another one.
I only need, for example, to put some new entry to a `Map`, without changing the collection.
With Apache Commons I would use `CollectionUtils.forAllDo`.

How can I get the same effect as `CollectionUtils.forAlDo` without having to return some value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a simple `foreach` loop for mutations. Guava doesn't like side-effects and you would only confuse readers with un-idiomatic code.

In order to handle your case, Guava should have had an `Effect<T>` interface with `apply(T): void` method along with a `Collections2#foreach(Effect<T>)` helper.

Comment: Or should i just use commons collection and get it over with?

Comment: I'd not. Having both guava and commons-collection in the same place seems messy. I'd rather write the `Effect` stuff myself.